# AVL tree - Why is it a must that the heights of the left and right children of some node may differ by 1?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, avl-tree

What's wrong with the heights of the left and right children of some node differ being by 2?

This is my first encounter with AVL trees, and I can't seem to understand why it is a must?

Really, what's wrong with the children being different by 2?

Regards

Comment: Because then it wouldn't be balanced, so it would invalidate the invariants, rendering it useless for further insertions and deletions.

Comment: You have to find some arbitrary way to define "balanced" versus "unbalanced". If they defined unbalanced to be >0 then you'd spend a lot more time balancing, if you made it >2 then you'd end up with longer look-up cost. AVL trees are designed for fast look-up, so making it >2 would also not be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a balanced binary tree can only differ by one. If you look at the algorithms that operate on the AVL trees, you'll see that this property is always maintained.

While it's possible to make some sort of data structure where the height differs by +- 2 at most, there is not real benefit in doing so. By leaving it as +- 1, you create a simpler, self-balancing data structure.

Comment: It's possible to create another useful sort of data structure without the +-1 invariant, but it will be just not an AVL tree any more.

Comment: @Oleksi: So if I understand you correctly ,if the difference would be +-2 , or more , then while searching for an element , or inserting / deleting , it might take `O(n)` ?

Comment: @ron No it can still be done in O(log(n)) because it's a constant difference, but why would you let it be +- 2? It's not any faster, but the algorithms become a little more complicated. In fact, they'd be slightly slower too (but still asymptotically O(log(n)). You're basically not using an AVL tree anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Well that's the concept of an AVL tree, the height of left and right childs must not differ by at most one.

From Wikipedia

> In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node
>   differ by at most one.

Since it's balanced, this make the search 0(logn), so it's faster than a non-balanced binary tree, where all the elements could be on the left, making it 0(n)